# All I want to do is have access to a user friendly console while on my android device to be able to use my google cloud. Is there such an app?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, google-cloud-ml

I downloaded the cloud console app but there is nothing to open up a command line. I'm generally at work and need to access google cloud remotely, idealy from my phone. I want to believe there is a nice way to do this with out generating a key pair and using something like "JuiceSSH". I'm sure I am overlooking something simple here. Hopefully this is a simple problem.

I'm simply trying to unzip and train an image set but I cant do it from work unless I can use my phone :/

Please and thank you everyone!

Comment: I do realize I could usw remote desktop also and usw the console that way.

Answer (score 0):

I started a free vm instance and used the console app to connect via ssh. Instead of from a 3rd party ssh application. This was exactly what I was looking for.